# Is it true that $\mathbb{P}(A \cap B \cap C) = \mathbb{P}(A \cap C)\mathbb{P}(B \cap C)$ when $A$ and $B$ are independent?

Tags: probability

It is generally not true that $\mathbb{P}(A \cap B \cap C) = \mathbb{P}(A \cap C)\mathbb{P}(B \cap C)$ - to see this consider a single coin toss and let $A$ be the event of getting a head, $B$ of getting a tail, and $C$ the event the coin lands.

Is it still false when $A$ and $B$ are independent? I have been unable to find either a proof or counterexample.

Comment: Hint : Try $B=C$.

Comment: Of course, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that your equality is equivalent to
$$\mathbb{P}((A \cap C) \cap(B \cap C)) = \mathbb{P}(A \cap C)\mathbb{P}(B \cap C)$$

This tells you that your equality is true precisely when $A \cap C$ and $B \cap C$ are independent.

It is easy to come up with examples where $A,B$ are independent but $A \cap C$ and $B \cap C$ are not.

Comment: This is a nice way of putting it. As in the comment from Captain Lama, taking $B=C$ gives one such example.